# Flash Media Server calling a page that returns JSON data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, parsing, flash-media-server

I am very new to Flash development.

I have an asp.net mvc site that has a controller action that returns JSON.

I have a Flash Media Server setup that needs to call that controller action every 15 minutes to get the current schedule. I can get the FMS to call the site (and every 15 minutes no problem) and I am getting the JSON right now as a string, but I need to parse it from the string to objects, in order to use the data returned.

Any pointers or ideas would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Chambers has an AS3 library on github (https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib). One of the libraries is for JSON serialization and parsing. Here's his example of it in a Flex MXML document, but would be the same in AS3 ( you basically get the JSON data, then call JSON.decode() on it to get an Array. ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns="*" 
layout="absolute"
creationComplete="service.send()" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

        private function onJSONLoad(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            var rawData:String = String(event.result);
            var arr:Array = (JSON.decode(rawData) as Array);

            var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(arr);

            grid.dataProvider = dp;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:HTTPService
    id="service"
    resultFormat="text"
    url="http://weblogs.macromedia.com/mesh/mashedpotato.json"
    result="onJSONLoad(event)" />

<mx:DataGrid id="grid" right="10" left="10" top="10" bottom="10">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Service" dataField="src"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="title"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Flash media server at least when I asked the question only supported Action Script Version 1. I did find a code file that would handle JSON for AS1, ended up not needing to use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a webservice call from FMS to get the data. In Actionscript 1, I think you should be able to use eval() to get an object that you can then query.

```
var callback = mWebService.NewGuid();
mWebService.onResult = function(resultString){
    var resultObject = eval(resultString);
    trace(resultObject.mProperty1);
}
```